# Array dinamico en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, array

Tengo la siguiente inquietud. Dentro del controlador, recibo una petición post que proviene de un formulario dinamico. Los parametros los recibo como los muestro en el capture. Ahora, sabe alguno como puedo extraer dichos parametros? Tomando en cuenta que en algunos casos pueden ser más de dos o un solo parametro.

[image: Array dinámico en laravel]

Tomando en cuenta que envio los valores de esta forma: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: con un foreach?

Comment: Ya lo intenté, igual se queda en el valor del token.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas para acceder a los valores recibidos, yo prefiero este método:

```
$request->key;
```

Pero como pueden ser muchos, lo más fácil es iterar con el método all() del request:

```
foreach($request->all() as $key => $item) {
   // utilizar los valores... 
   dump($key);
   dump($item);
}
```

Asumo que estás inyectando el request al método que recibe.

Comment: Si, estoy en el método que recibe. Al iterar con el foreach, me toma solo el valor del token.

Comment: @ErainMoya acabo de realizar una prueba igual a lo que haces y me funciona perfectamente, recibo los valores y los puedo ver con el dump (ver edición de la respuesta).

Comment: Listo!! Me los muestra con el dum. Solo me faltaba acceder a cada elemneto.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes acceder a ellos con

```
$request->input('key')
$request->key
$request->input('key', 'valor por defecto')
$request->input() // para traer todos los inputs como un array asociativo
$request->all()
```

**EDITO**

Perdón no había entendido bien tu pregunta

con request input o all puedes traer todos los inputs

y con un foreach haces un filtro

```
    foreach ($request->input() as $name => $value) {
        if ($name != '_token') {
            echo 'nombre: '.$name.'<br>';
            echo 'valor: '. $value.'<br>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Excelente aporte, gracias!!